# TypeError when trying to explain weights of XGBoost Classifier

Tags: python, xgboost, eli5

I am working on implementing XGBoost on the Titanic dataset provided by [Kaggle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaggle). I found the package ELI5 and the tutorial for implementing this package with XGBoost on the Titanic dataset at this link on the official documentation for ELI 5 ([Jupyter Notebook tutorial](https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/eli5/blob/master/notebooks/xgboost-titanic.ipynb)). While on the third section of the notebook, I attempt to apply the *show_weights()* function to my classifier, but I get the following error after running these lines of code.

```
[1]from eli5 import show_weights, explain_weights
[2]show_weights(clf, vec=vec)

Out[2]: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Clearly it's not interpreting the clf object created in section 2. There's no information of the ELI5 package being incompatible with XGBoost in either packages' documentation.

Comment: Show the full traceback error.

Answer (score 4):

I can reproduce that same error when using ELI5 with XGBoost 1.4.0.

However, with XGBoost version 1.3.0 and earlier versions the error goes away.

Downgrade if you can.

Comment: While not ideal, this solution did work for me. As of 27 OCT 2021, ELI5's GitHub has an open issue about this problem: https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/eli5/pull/407. If you're likewise running into this problem, I suggest that you go and up-vote the issue!